# Passing data from app to background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-service

I want to pass some data(e.g. string values) of foreground app to background agent in window phone application.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at "Communication Between Foreground Application and Background Agent" in this link (halfway down the page):

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Link is broken, here it is over again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx. More information on the topic is also available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsolatedStorage and ApplicationSettings